# Selected Row DataGrid in WPF (VB.NET)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I use WPF in language vb.net. Specific data is brought to `DataGrid`. When select a row at `DataGrid` but it is not selected exactly selected row.

[image]

when select row[2] in `DataGrid` but it select row[0]. 
How to select exactly selected row?

[Source code here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16661867/WpfApplication2.rar)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code because it is blocked at work however I always did something like this.

DataGrid1.SelectedItem = DataGrid1.Items.Item(2)